# Navigating after an async function

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

I am using the `AutoRouter` package to handle all of my navigation logic. Everything seems to be working so far but I am encountering the following error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

This happens after I click on a button that has the following logic in its on press callback:

```dart
Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text)
                        .then(
                          (value) => AutoRouter.of(context)
                              .popAndPush(const HomeRoute()),
                        );
```

I have also tried the recommended method:

```dart
Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
if (context.mounted) {
AutoRouter.of(context).popAndPush(const HomeRoute())
}
```

In this case, the navigation logic never runs because the `context.mounted` expression resolves to false.

I realize that this issue is common when dialogues or pop ups are there as the context for them is different than the context of the scaffold. I have tried to use the context by declaring a global scaffold key as well and that also did not work.

I am, however, using a page view where the first page is a landing page, second is login page and third one is a registration page. I doubt that that is the cause of the issue. In any case, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Save a reference to the AutoRouter before the async function and use that to navigate after.

```
final router = AutoRouter.of(context);
await asyncFunction();
router.popAndPush(const HomeRoute());
```